# flexunit: Parametrized tests

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit4

I am trying to run  a parametrized tests... Was trying to implement it like it explained here:
http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Parameterized_Test_Styles

Here is what my test case looking

```
import org.flexunit.runners.Parameterized;

[RunWith("org.flexunit.runners.Parameterized")]
public class ArrayBasedStackTests
{       
    [Paremeters]
    public static var stackProvider:Array = [new ArrayBasedStack(), new LinkedListBasedStack()] ;

    private var _stack:IStack;

    public function ArrayBasedStackTests(param:IStack)
    {
        _stack = param;
    }


    [Before]
    public function setUp():void
    {
    }

    [After]
    public function tearDown():void
    {
    }

    [Test ( description = "Checks isEmpty method of the stack. For empty stack", dataProvider="stackProvider" )]
    public function isEmptyStackPositiveTest():void
    {
        var stack:IStack = _stack;
        assertEquals( true, stack.isEmpty() );
    }
```

But this code throws following initializing Error:

> Error: Custom runner class org.flexunit.runners.Parameterized should
>   be linked into project and implement IRunner. Further it needs to have
>   a constructor which either just accepts the class, or the class and a
>   builder.

Need help to fix it

### UPDATE

I've updated the code so it looks like this

```
    [RunWith("org.flexunit.runners.Parameterized")]
public class ArrayBasedStackTests
{       
    private var foo:Parameterized;

    [Parameters]
    public static function stacks():Array
    {
        return  [ [new ArrayBasedStack()], [new LinkedListBasedStack()] ] ;
    }

    [Before]
    public function setUp():void
    {
    }

    [After]
    public function tearDown():void
    {
    }

    [Test ( description = "Checks isEmpty method of the stack. For empty stack", dataProvider="stacks")]
    public function isEmptyStackPositiveTest(stack:IStack):void
    {
        assertEquals( true, _stack.isEmpty() );
    }
```

It works. But the result is a bit strange. I have 4 test executed instead of 2. (I have 2 items in data provider, so cant get why do I have 4 tests).

Output

http://screencast.com/t/G8DHbcjDUkJ

Comment: It sounds like there's a class missing, or it's using the wrong version. What version of FlexUnit are you linking against? (right-click project > Properties > ActionScript Build Path > Library Path). Is the code merged or does it use RSLs? Also it seems the [Parameters] meta-tag is misspelled here.

Comment: Good spot about spell mistake. Fixed. here what I have in build path http://screencast.com/t/xfEpEn7BALg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[Parameters]` meta-data specifies that the parameters are passed to the constructor of the test - so the test class is called for each parameter. You also have the `dataProvider` set for the specific test method, so the test method is also called once for each parameter. Two calls for the test, and two calls to the method, ends up running four tests.

The solution is to either use `[Parameters]` meta-tag which specifies the data to use for the whole test class, or use the `dataProvider` for each test method, but not both with the same data at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the static reference to `Paramaterized`, as shown here:

```
    import org.flexunit.runners.Parameterized;

[RunWith("org.flexunit.runners.Parameterized")]
public class MyTestNGTest
{       

    private var foo:Parameterized;
    ...
```

Basically, that error means that the `[Runner]` defined isn't available at runtime, which occurs if there is no static reference in the class to cause it to get linked in.

In FlexUnit 4.5.1, this approach changed to using `[Rule]`'s like so:

```
public class MyTestNGTest
{
    [Rule]
    public function paramaterizedRule:ParamaterizedRule = new ParamaterizedRule();

    ...
 }
```

However, I can't seem to see an actual implementation of `IMethodRule` for paramaterized tests (that example is fictional).